# convert class libraries from asp.net 3.5 to 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, class-library

I have a Solution that has two class libraries.  I'm trying to convert the whole solution from asp.net 3.5 to 4.

Right now the libraries are in my Visual Studio 2008 projects folder. I've installed VS 2010.  Should I just copy the libraries from the 2008 project folder to my 2010 project folder and open them in VS 2010?

What is the best practices for this?  The entire solution is in a single folder in my VS 2008 Project folder, and each application and class library is in their own subfolder.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open the sln-file from VS 2010 and VS 2010 will convert all your projects to VS 2010 automatically.

Then you need to change target framework from 3.5 to 4.0. You need to do that for each project by right-click->Properties in solution explorer and on the "Application tab" change "Target framework" to 4.0.

Comment: Thanks, but the last project I did that for it left the projects in my Visual Studio 2005 folder instead of moving it to my Visual Studio 2008 folder.  Has this changed in VS 2010?

Comment: @drpcken, No, the project remains where it is located. You can move/copy the project to any folder you like, that is up to you where you want your projects.

Answer (score 1):

Could just open the 2008 solution in 2010, it will convert it.  If you don't need a 2008 solution that should be fine.  And as long as you don't need a 2008 solution no need to copy anything.  And if you don't use any specific 2010 features you should be able to copy the 2008 solution file and have both a 2008 and 2010 file.  But just changing the targeting might be better.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like to start a new project and copy the files over because I don't trust/like these conversions 100%. I just feel better if I start fresh. But as other said you can copy your project anywhere. I don't use the Visual Studio 20** project folders as I separate my pure .NET projects from web applications and so on.

But you can try to see if there's any difference between a clean VS2010 solution and a VS2008 solution that has been converted and then set the target to .NET 4.0. The differences will probably be in the .sln and .csproj files. You can use Notepad++'s compare feature.

Comment: What part don't you trust? The conversion mostly changes version info in the .sln file, regenerates resource files and other generated files.

Comment: Why use Notepad++ when you diff in your version control system?

Comment: @Albin: 1) To be honest I don't really know. Maybe it's as simple as you said for libraries (what drpcken is of course asking about), but for ASP.NET MVC I think it wasn't as clean in the beginning. I guess I just like a clean start. I'll should probably try to do a test I mentioned again. 2) In the case I was taking about you have two separate projects. AFAIK versioning tools work between repository and current files. Otherwise I of course use their diff :)